# How can I tell what versions of MinGW32 and MinGW64 (via Git Bash) I have installed?

Tags: git, bash, mingw

When I originally installed Git for Windows, I (somehow) ended up with two copies of Git Bash - one running MinGW32, one running MinGW64.

Given there's no command like `mingw --version` I could run, how can I determine what versions of these packages I currently have installed? I've been having some trouble with MinGW64 and wanted to see if there was a newer version available than what I have currently.

(For what it's worth, the latest version of MinGW64 for Windows appears to be 3.3.0 ([source](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download)) although I'm not entirely certain whether I should be looking at the Win-Builds downloads or not - anyway, that's probably a separate question.)

To get the version, I've tried:

- Checking the icon context menu in each console window. MinGW64's options has an About window that says 'mintty 2.0.3'. mintty seems to be a terminal emulator for Cygwin (I also have Cygwin installed). MinGW32's properties doesn't seem to have a visible version number.
- Looking for a `gcc` executable in either of the terminal's `bin`'s that I could run with the `--version` flag; neither of them have it (and I'm not sure either how tightly gcc is integrated with the terminal).
- Running `sh --version`. On MinGW64 I get version 4.3.42 of GNU bash, and on MinGW32 I get version 3.1.23 of GNU bash. However, I don't think this is the version number of the respective MinGW projects.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`uname -a`

This is a common linux command to show the version info of OS.

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thank you!